# Setting a NSGridView Height to the height of its content views

Tags: swift, cocoa, autolayout

I defined a gridview like this:

```
let lb01 = NSTextField(labelWithString: "01")
....
let gridView = NSGridView(views:
  [ [empty, lb01],
    [empty, lb02],
    [lb03, lb04]
  ])

gridView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false  
self.addSubview(gridView)

let layoutViewMap = ["another View": anotherView, "GridView": gridView]
var constraintList = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
let constraintV = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints( withVisualFormat: "V:[GridView]-50-[anotherView]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: layoutViewMap)
constraintList += constraintV
let constraintH = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints( withVisualFormat: "|-20-[GridView(==300)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: layoutViewMap)
constraintList += constraintH

NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraintList)
```

In some situations the grid view grows in height

I can define an explicit height with

```
let constraintV = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints( withVisualFormat: "V:[GridView(==70)]-50-[anotherView]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: layoutViewMap)
```

How can I archive, the height is not given explicitly but calculated for the height etc to its content

Comment: Are you just trying to get NSGridView to hug its content?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like what you want is your NSGridView to hug the contents it contains. To do this, you just need to boost the `contentHuggingPriority` on the view.

```
gridView.setContentHuggingPriority(600, for: .horizontal)
gridView.setContentHuggingPriority(600, for: .vertical)
```

600 is somewhat arbitrary (default is 249 which is just below `.defaultLow`), but it comes from the [WWDC 2016 Auto Layout talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/236/)